# SQL connection is not established if called from express request

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express

I am building my first Node.JS API and I have a problem that I'm trying to solve since yesterday.

Basically, when someone connects to my endpoint, I need to fetch some data from SQL database. The problem is that the connection to SQL is not established at all.
I created a simplified version of my code for readability:

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();

class Server {
    constructor() {
        this.sqlAccessor = new ModelsSqlAccessor();
        this.app = express();
        this.app.get("/api/endpoint1", async (req, res) => {
            let data = await this.sqlAccessor.executeQuery("some query");
            res.send(data);
        });
    }

    start() {
        this.app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening on port 3000..."));
    }
}


class ModelsSqlAccessor {
    constructor() {
        let config = {
            userName: process.env.MJIOT_MODELSDB_USER,
            password: process.env.MJIOT_MODELSDB_PASS,
            server: process.env.MJIOT_MODELSDB_SERVER,
            options: {
                database: process.env.MJIOT_MODELSDB_DATABASE,
                encrypt: true
            }
        };
        this.connection = new Connection(config);
    }

    executeQuery(query) {
        let conn = this.connection;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            conn.on('connect', function(err) {
                console.log('INSIDE CONNECT');
                //execute query...
            });
        });
    }
}

let server = new Server();
server.start();
```

So, in this example I have 2 classes, where Server is a wrapper around Express and ModelsSqlAccessor is a way to access SQL DB.
Inside of executeQuery(query) method of ModelsSqlAccessor I am connecting to database. When the connection occurs (or there is an error with connection) message should be displayed "INSIDE CONNECT".
In the given example, this message is not displayed at all. Instead, when request comes, the response never comes - my node app just never returns from executeQuery("some query") call and never returns any value to the client.

Strange for me is the fact that if I move this call:

```
let data = await this.sqlAccessor.executeQuery("some query");
```

somewhere else (for example a few lines up in the constructor of Server, before GET endpoint is setup (removing AWAIT keyword of course, since constructor cannot be ASYNC)), the connection is established when my app is run and I see "INSIDE CONNECT" message.

What is the problem here? Why the connection is never established if this call is inside of endpoint handler?

Comment: You are missing the `connect` event. By the time you register for `connect` event, it has already emmited since you made the connection in `ModelsSqlAccessor` 's constructor.

Comment: @Xaqron You are right! That's how one ends up reading Microsoft documentation (https://docs.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs). Above connection.on('connect', function(err).. they clearly state "Attempt to connect and execute queries if connection goes through". That's why I though that this line actually initializes the connection, although the syntax is obviously more like registering an event handler, so I could maybe think about that myself. Generally I don't like all these callback-based APIs of node. I wonder why they didn't go with Promises

Comment: One more thing - do you think it is a good idea to keep the connection open all the time that node is running or maybe I should initialize a new connection with each request? Aha, and please submit an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I would keep the connection open to reduce the cost. Although it depends on how actually the underlying library is developed (it may already take care of that).

Comment: @Xaqron What do you mean by the "cost"? Time of response?

Comment: CPU, RAM, Bandwidth... usage. One consequence would be increased time of response.